# I keep getting a -1700 error

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to write a script that will open finder, open the applications window and press command+a then command+o using [this script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utGKy.png) but every time I try to run it the error code you can see comes up. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plus sign `+` is a mathematical operator and the enumerated constants cannot be added.

The syntax you are looking for is

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "a" using {shift down, command down}
end tell
```

Comment: That really helped, Thanks @vadian